# How do I return several values based on color match in Excel?

Tags: excel, function, indexing, colors, return

I have a page with data, and a page with key figures (revenue, profits, etc.). On the data page, I color the "good" rows green. I want to have a function that returns certain cells (revenue, for example), based on the green color. I have made a colormatch function in VBA, so what I need now is a way to utilize this function in a new function that returns the green rows. I want the color to be the only thing that the returns are based on. The order of the returned values doesn't matter. Could be alphabetic or anything else. As long as they are returned automatically to my 'key figures' page.

Comment: Please, post your code, what have you tried, where are you stuck and what errors are you getting. read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I have tried various different functions. I tried using an index- match function where I utilized the colormatches inside it. I tried using the if function combined with index and colormatch. It seems as if the obstacle is that I can't figure out how to return values in a random order, and not based on a specific other value. For instance, if I used the mentioned functions and wanted to return a value from an index based on a match between two specific unique values, it would have been easy. But I want to return several values in a random order, as the color match applies to more than one.